# A matrix with the highest number of eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra

Is is true to say that the matrix with the highest number of eigenvalues is the scalar matrix?

Comment: Based on your comments below, you don't mean "scalar matrix".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a square matrix with $n$ rows and columns the maximal number of possible eigenvalues is $n$. If you want pairwise distinct eigenvalues, this is the case e.g. for the diagonal matrix with $1,2,\dots,n$ on the diagonal.

Answer (score 1):

Most certainly not.

For example, the scalar matrix

$$I=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
has only one eigenvalue. On the other hand,

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{bmatrix}$$

has **two** eigenvalues, $I$, the scalar matrix, has a lower number of eigenvalues than $A$, so we cannot say that a scalar matrix has the highest number of eigenvalues.

Comment: I meant to say diagonal matrix, but thanks!

Comment: @gbox The answer is still no, since $I$ is diagonal and has only one eigenvalue.

Comment: Yes diagonal with no same entires

Comment: Although it is true that a particular diagonal matrix maximises the number of eigenvalues.

Comment: @gbox Then the answer is yes. However, there are also non-diagonal matrices with the maximal number of eigenvalues.

Comment: @5xum is there an example?

Comment: @gbox Plenty of them. $$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2\\2&1\end{bmatrix}$$ is one.